# Vue + Webpack staging/preproduction configuration

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

Here's what I'm looking to do: at my work, we currently have multiple environments to work in. We have multiple environments for development, one for staging (which we call "preproduction"), and our production instance. We've started working in Vue for our frontend and are using webpack for bundling (specifically, the `vue-cli` and the webpack template for the `vue-cli`). We want to create a configuration of the webpack template for preproduction, so we can setup configuration options in the project based on whether we are deploying to preproduction or production. Here's the template we created as a starting point: https://github.com/JasonGrubb/webpack. The preproduction environment was created as a clone of the production environment. It's working so far, but we want the Chrome vue-devtools to work in the preproduction environment. Any suggestions on how to configure webpack for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation points to do so. How exactly do you exceute your preproduction environment? Is it a virtual host or are you using 'npm run dev' in the console?
Using 'npm run dev' with that boilerplate should allow you to access it on localhost:8080 and the Vue dev tools should be available.

Comment: No, I'm using `npm run dev` for my local development environment. I'm using `npm run build_preprod` which is a script I created that's nearly identical to `npm run build` to build out the `index.html` and `bundle.js` files. These files are then placed on a server machine and served using Apache or nginx